# flujos streams con archivos *.dat

Tags: java, java-swing, java-stream

estoy realizando una aplicación con swing y necesito enlazar datos que introduzco por dicha aplicación a un archivo *.dat. El caso es que tengo tres paquetes y cada paquete con su *.java:

Paquete 1: Clase Vehiculos con sus atributos y métodos setters y getters.

Paquete 2: manejo del fichero.

Paquete 3: Interfaz swing de la aplicación.

Mi duda es como proceder en los flujos o streams; ¿debo abrir/cerrar uno desde el paquete 2 a cada uno de los otros dos paquetes? ¿como enlazo los paquetes entre ellos?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

RandomAccessFile

Esta es una clase primitiva que implementa los interfaces  DataInput y DataOutput y sirve para leer y escribir datos.

La construcción requiere de una cadena que contenga una ruta válida a un archivo o de un archivo File. 
Hay un segundo parámetro obligatorio que se llama modo. El modo es una cadena que puede contener una r(lectura), w(escritura) o ambas, rw. Hay que capturar la excepción FileNotFoundcuando se ejecuta el constructor.

```
File f=new File("prueba.txt"); 
RandomAccessFile archivo = new RandomAccessFile( f, "rw");
```

Los métodos fundamentales son:

-> `seek(long pos)`. Permite colocarse en una posición concreta, contada en bytes, en el archivo.

Lo que se coloca es el puntero de acceso que es la señal que marca la posición a leer o escribir.

-> `long getFilePointer().Posición` actual del puntero de acceso?

->`long length()`. Devuelve el tamaño del archivo.

->  `readBoolean`, `readByte`, `readChar`, `readInt`, `readDouble`, `readFloat`, `readUTF`, `readLine`.
  Funciones de lectura.

Leen un dato del tipo indicado. En el caso de readUTFlee una cadena en formato Unicode.

?     `writeBoolean`, `writeByte`, `writeBytes`, `writeChar`,`writeChars` `writeInt`, `writeDouble`, `writeFloat`, `writeUTF`, `writeLine`.

Funciones de escritura.

Todas reciben como parámetro, el dato a escribir. 
Escribe encima de lo ya escrito. 
Para escribir al final hay que colocar el puntero de acceso al final del archivo.